# Windows bat file: run

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a script, which do this: start->run->"smth".
How can I write it in bat file to achieve the same task. Thanks.

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to run by Going to Start button, clicking Run and then typing your command? What is it?

Comment: To connect a server I'm pushing start->run and type \\server_address.
I want a bat file to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to browse using explorer, which `Run` will do, but batch will try and execute. Try putting this in the batch file:

```
explorer \\server_address
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called sample.bat and make its contents:

```
@echo off

echo opening server location

start "" \\192.168.2.1

pause
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. It doesn't work for me. I need to connect to a server, and what I'm doing is doing to run and typing \\server_address. I want a bat file do this.